# Nexenta/OpenSolaris filer kernel panic/crash

Tags: nfs, zfs, opensolaris, nexenta, deadlock

I've an [x4540 Sun storage server](http://www.sun.com/servers/x64/x4540/specs.xml) running [NexentaStor Enterprise](http://www.nexentastor.org/). It's serving NFS over 10GbE CX4 for several VMWare vSphere hosts. There are 30 virtual machines running.

For the past few weeks, I've had random crashes spaced 10-14 days apart. This system used to open OpenSolaris and was stable in that arrangement. The crashes trigger the automated system recovery feature on the hardware, forcing a hard system reset.

Here's the [output from mdb debugger](https://serverfault.com/questions/247614/debug-nexenta-opensolaris-core-files):

```
panic[cpu5]/thread=ffffff003fefbc60: 
Deadlock: cycle in blocking chain


ffffff003fefb570 genunix:turnstile_block+795 ()
ffffff003fefb5d0 unix:mutex_vector_enter+261 ()
ffffff003fefb630 zfs:dbuf_find+5d ()
ffffff003fefb6c0 zfs:dbuf_hold_impl+59 ()
ffffff003fefb700 zfs:dbuf_hold+2e ()
ffffff003fefb780 zfs:dmu_buf_hold+8e ()
ffffff003fefb820 zfs:zap_lockdir+6d ()
ffffff003fefb8b0 zfs:zap_update+5b ()
ffffff003fefb930 zfs:zap_increment+9b ()
ffffff003fefb9b0 zfs:zap_increment_int+68 ()
ffffff003fefba10 zfs:do_userquota_update+8a ()
ffffff003fefba70 zfs:dmu_objset_do_userquota_updates+de ()
ffffff003fefbaf0 zfs:dsl_pool_sync+112 ()
ffffff003fefbba0 zfs:spa_sync+37b ()
ffffff003fefbc40 zfs:txg_sync_thread+247 ()
ffffff003fefbc50 unix:thread_start+8 ()
```

Any ideas what this means?

Additional information. I don't believe I have any quotas enabled on the filesystem or at a per-user level.

```
========== Volumes and Folders ===========
NAME                    USED    AVAIL   REFER  MOUNTED QUOTA  DEDUP COMPRESS
syspool/rootfs-nmu-000  9.84G   195G    3.84G  yes     none   off   off
syspool/rootfs-nmu-001  79.5K   195G    1.16G  no      none   off   off
syspool/rootfs-nmu-002  89.5K   195G    2.05G  no      none   off   off
syspool/rootfs-nmu-003  82.5K   195G    6.30G  no      none   off   off
vol1/AueXXXch           33.9G   1.28T   23.3G  yes     none   on    on
vol1/CXXXG              8.72G   1.28T   6.22G  yes     none   on    on
vol1/CoaXXXuce          97.8G   1.28T   61.4G  yes     none   on    on
vol1/HXXXco             58.1G   1.28T   41.1G  yes     none   off   on
vol1/HXXXen             203G    1.28T   90.0G  yes     none   off   on
vol1/HXXXny             9.65G   1.28T   8.48G  yes     none   off   on
vol1/InXXXuit           2.03G   1.28T   2.03G  yes     none   off   on
vol1/MiXXXary           196G    1.28T   105G   yes     none   off   on
vol1/RoXXXer            45.5G   1.28T   28.7G  yes     none   off   on
vol1/TudXXXanch         6.06G   1.28T   4.54G  yes     none   off   on
vol1/aXXXa              774M    1.28T   774M   yes     none   off   off
vol1/ewXXXte            46.4G   1.28T   46.4G  yes     none   on    on
vol1/foXXXce            774M    1.28T   774M   yes     none   off   off
vol1/saXXXe             69K     1.28T   31K    yes     none   off   on
vol1/vXXXre             72.4G   1.28T   72.4G  yes     none   off   on
vol1/xXXXp              29.0G   1.28T   18.6G  yes     none   off   on
vol1/xXXXt              100G    1.28T   52.4G  yes     none   off   on
vol2/AuXXXch            22.9G   2.31T   22.9G  yes     none   on    on
vol2/FamXXXree          310G    2.31T   230G   yes     none   off   on
vol2/LAXXXty            605G    2.31T   298G   yes     none   off   on
vol2/McXXXney           147G    2.31T   40.3G  yes     none   off   on
vol2/MoXXXri            96.8G   2.31T   32.6G  yes     none   off   on
vol2/TXXXta             676G    2.31T   279G   yes     none   off   on
vol2/VXXXey             210G    2.31T   139G   yes     none   off   on
vol2/vmXXXe2            2.69G   2.31T   2.69G  yes     none   off   on
```

Comment: Nexenta won't help you with this?

Comment: No help as of yet. Posted at: http://www.nexentastor.org/boards/1/topics/2109

Comment: NexentaStor Enterprise is sold with a support contract, while you're linking to the open source forums..

Comment: I have not purchased the license for this particular unit yet. I'm waiting until this issue is resolved before moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved permanently by recreating all of the zpools under Nexenta. There was a lot of baggage carried along with the zpools as they were imported from an OpenSolaris installation. And while I imported and upgraded the pools and filesystems, the stability wasn't there until everything was rebuilt.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about this setup but,

ffffff003fefb820 zfs:zap_lockdir+6d () seems to indicate that the worker thread is locking the directory and then mutex_vector_enter tries to lock it too.

This all seems to stem from a situation that begins with updating quota. If its possible you might want to consider turning quotas off if they are unnecessary.

Its only a workaround rather than a fix and I have no idea if it'll work as expected! But might be worth a try.

Comment: They are definitely unnecessary in this case. I'm not using this as anything but a vmware storage solution. I'll dig in and see if something indicates that quotas are on by default.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace references "userquota" which is not typically used by our customers. Note
that it is separate from the file system quotas that you can also set. I encourage you
to turn off user quotas if you can, especially since you think they are unnecessary, but
also I encourage you to file a support ticket if you have a support contract. This can be sent from the Web GUI, which would then include diagnostics from your system in the ticket.

Comment: How do I check if userquota is set somewhere? I've never done this explicitly.

Comment: There are some examples in the user guide located at http://www.nexenta.com/corp/static/docs-stable/NexentaStor-UserGuide.pdf. In NMC you can use the command "setup folder <foldername> property userquota" then enter the user name, then enter "none" to remove the quota. If you aren't sure if the user has a quota you can first do "show folder <foldername> property userquota".

Comment: I updated my original comment a few days ago with the output showing that the userquota parameter is "none" on all filesystems.

Comment: Perhaps this is obvious, but there is a difference between (a) creating a folder for each user and assigning it a quota, and (b) creating a folder and assigning a userquota. The above output seems to be indicating that you are not doing (a). But I am trying to verify that you are not doing (b).

Comment: `nmc@xx:/vol1/xt$ show folder vol1/xt property userquota
SystemCallError: bad property list: invalid property 'userquota'`

Comment: I never assigned quotas to any folders, and I don't have individual users on this system. It's purely vmware storage via NFS with a couple of iSCSI LUNs. There's no file-level access outside of that.